# need help aligning form elements

Tags: css, html, forms

[image: form alignment]

I want to create a form that alligns like the attached image. I wan't the text fields to be inline with the input tag, and have all the feilds in a verticle allignment to the right of the form. [(see image here)][2]

I have this html:

```css
#form_container {
  width: 300px;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#form_container input {
  width: 60%;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

#form_container textarea {
  width: 60%;
  clear: both;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

#form_container label {
  display: block;
  width: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div id="form_container">

  <h1>Add Event</h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="event_form">
    <label for="textfield">Name/location:</label>
    <input name="textfield" type="text" required id="location">

    <p>
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="textarea">Brief description:</label>
      <textarea name="textarea" cols="40" rows="4" required id="description"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="textfield2">Trip leader:</label>
      <input name="textfield2" type="text" required id="leader">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="tel">Leaders contact #:</label>
      <input name="tel" type="tel" required id="leader_phone" maxlength="10">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: you're missing a `<p>` after form init and a `</p>` after your last input

Comment: thanks, added it. Didn't fix the problem but may have fixed a future problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `color:#000000;` From this class `#form_container`

Give `float:left` to this class `#form_container label`

Remove `margin-left:40%;` from this classes `#form_container input`, `#form_container textarea`

Comment: Thankyou! Works perfectly. Will mark as correct answer in 6 minutes when it allows me to!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/4Nqz6/

```
#form_container{
    width: 300px;
    clear: both;
    margin-left:50px;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float: left;
}
#form_container p{float: left; width: 100%; margin:5px 0;}
#form_container input, #form_container textarea{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

#form_container textarea{
    width: 60%;
    max-width:300px;

}

#form_container label{
    display:block;
    font: normal 12px Arial;
    color: #000;
    float: left; width: 38%; line-height: 20px;
}
#form_container .button{margin-left: 38%;}
```

Comment: Yes, you've used basically the same method as Bindiya, works a treat. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste this code in your html and match with your image ...

**Your HTML CODE**

```
<body>

    <h1>Add New Event</h1>

    <div id="form_container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="event_form">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="textfield">Name/location:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="textfield" type="text" required id="location">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select>
                        <option>dd</option>
                        <option>01</option>
                        <option>02</option>
                     </select> :
                      <select>
                        <option>mm</option>
                        <option>01</option>
                        <option>02</option>
                     </select> :
                      <select>
                        <option>yy</option>
                        <option>2013</option>
                        <option>2014</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="textarea">Brief description:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <textarea name="textarea" cols="40" rows="4" required id="description"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                     <label for="textfield2">Trip leader:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <input name="textfield2" type="text" required id="leader">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                      <label for="tel">Leaders contact #:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                      <input name="tel" type="tel" required id="leader_phone" maxlength="10">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" style="width:20%">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

</div>
    </body>
```

**Your CSS :**

```
#form_container{
                float:left;
                clear: both;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                font-family: "Calibri";
                }
                h1{
                    font-family: "Calibri"; 
                }
                #form_container input{
                    width: 60%;
                    clear: both;
                }
                #btn_submit{
                    width: 20%;
                    clear: both;
                }
                #form_container textarea{
                    width: 60%;
                    clear: both;
                    max-width:300px;
                }
```